# How can i use multi select dropdown on tables using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datatable

Here is my select dropdown

```
<select  ng-model="searchtxt">
<option value="">Select Institute</option>
<option ng-repeat="user in products | unique : 'Institute'" value="{{user.Institute}}">{{user.Institute}}</option></select>
```

Here is my table

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Institute<th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="user in products>
<td>{{user.Institute}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</table>
```

Here is my json

```
$scope.products = [
{"Institute": "Academy for Coaching Excellence"}
{"Institute": "Sample for training Excellence"}
{"Institute": "Demo for education Excellence"}
{"Institute": "Academy for best Excellence"}
];
```

I have tried following

```
$scope.selectedRows = [];
$scope.select = function(item) {
item.selected ? item.selected = false : item.selected = true;
}
$scope.getAllSelectedRows = function() {
var selectedRows = $filter("filter")($scope.users, {
selected: true
}, true);    
$scope.selectedRows = selectedRows;
}
```

Can anyone help me to achive the optimal solution in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

A multiple select is a regular select with the `multiple` property added to it. In angular, whatever you select will be bound to the `ng-model` variable.

I'm not sure if this example answers your question, but it shows how to access the data from the multi-select menu

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{
      "Institute": "Academy for Coaching Excellence"
    }, {
      "Institute": "Sample for training Excellence"
    }, {
      "Institute": "Demo for education Excellence"
    }, {
      "Institute": "Academy for best Excellence"
    }];

    $scope.searchtxt = [];

  }]);
```

```css
.selected {
  color: green;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div>Select Institute</div>

    <select multiple ng-model="searchtxt">
      <option ng-repeat="user in products" value="{{user.Institute}}">{{user.Institute}}</option>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Institute
          <th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in products">
          <td ng-class="{'selected':searchtxt.indexOf(user.Institute)>-1}">{{user.Institute}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr> $scope.searchtxt: {{searchtxt}}

  </div>
</div>
```